# Google transliteration Language Selection

Tags: php, jquery, google-translate

I'm trying to implement google transliteration in my website. It's working on all supported Indian languages. But when I select English it shows some error like 'Unsupported language en in targetLangCode array'. Please help me to resolve this issue.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-alpha1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        google.load("elements", "1", {
            packages: "transliteration"
        });
    </script> 
</head>
<body>
    <select name="langpair" style="height:32px; padding:0;" id="langpair" size="1">
        <option value="ENGLISH">Select one...</option>
        <option value="ENGLISH">English</option>
        <option value="HINDI">Hindi</option>
        <option value="BENGALI">BENGALI</option>
        <option value="TELUGU">Telugu</option>
        <option value="MARATHI">Marathi</option>
        <option value="TAMIL">Tamil</option>
        <option value="URDU">Urdu</option>
        <option value="KANNADA">Kannada</option>
        <option value="GUJARATI">Gujarati</option>
        <option value="MALAYALAM">Malayalam</option>
        <option value="PUNJABI">PUNJABI</option>
        <option value="SANSKRIT">SANSKRIT</option>
        <option value="NEPALI">Nepali</option>
        <option value="ARABIC">Arabic</option>
        <option value="SINDHI">Sindhi</option>
    </select>
    <br/>

    <textarea class="form-control" maxlength="160" id="message" name="message" rows="3" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
    <hr>

    <br/>
    <script>
        var options = {
            shortcutKey: 'ctrl+g',
            transliterationEnabled: true,
            sourceLanguage: 'en',
            destinationLanguage: ['or'],
          };
          var control = new google.elements.transliteration.TransliterationControl(options);
           control.makeTransliteratable(['message']);

          $("#langpair").change(function() {

            var data = this.value;

            var destinationLanguage = google.elements.transliteration.LanguageCode[data];
            control.setLanguagePair('en', destinationLanguage);
          });

    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: How on earth are we going to help you? You put it as `php` and `jquery` tag and i can't see anything. You expect us to guess or maybe we're just some magician to make your code work without viewing it?

Comment: Please add the code that you are running when you see the error and explain the things you have already tried to resolve the issue

Comment: it shows error only when destinationLanguage is 'en' (english)